# publish android library to amazon cloud procedures

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aar, amazon-cloudwatch

I have downloaded the android aws document for Publish my android studio 2.2.2 library project to amazon cloud. But, these steps not for me.

can anybody suggest any other method to upload Android studio library project to Amazon cloud and make url for dependencies like Jcenter and Maven.

Comment: I refered this aws tutorial also.that is not clear to understand. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to host private Maven repos without the need to stand up and manage a server:

In order to host your assets on  Amazon S3, you’ll first have to set up an authenticated bucket to serve as your repository. That’s outside the scope of this article, but Amazon has some excellent [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/) detailing how to do that.

Once you create the bucket, you’ll need to add a bucket policy to ensure your authentication user has access to all files created within the bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1428433847297",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1428433844452",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/maven-user"
      },
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pixite-maven"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1428433844452",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/maven-user"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::pixite-maven/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that my group has access to list the pixite-maven bucket, and also permission to get and put objects in any subdirectories of the bucket. You can restrict this however you want according to Amazon’s documentation.

If you’re hosting both snapshots and releases in a single bucket (like I do), you’ll probably want to add those directories into the root of your bucket. Another option is to have two buckets that can be managed independently, one for snapshots and one for releases.

The next step is to ensure that you’re using gradle 2.4 for your project. This can be done by editing your gradle-wrapper.properties file, or by simply adding the following snippet to your root build.gradle file, and running ./gradlew wrapper.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4' }
```

Now, wherever you normally set the repositories you need access to (I use an allprojects {} block in my root build script), simply add your Amazon S3 bucket as a maven repository.

```
 repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://pixite-maven/releases"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
            }
        }
        maven {
            url "s3://pixite-maven/snapshots"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
            }
        }



  mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

Notice how the url of the repository is `s3://[bucket name]/[path]`. Also, since this is a private repository, I’m including my AwsCredentials in the maven block. While you could put your actual `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` directly in your build file, DON’T! Your build files shouldn’t ever include credentials, since then you can’t really manage access. Those values are exactly what’s in my build file, allowing it to read from the user specific gradle.properties file in my home directory. Here’s where I set the actual values, in **~/.gradle/gradle.properties:**

```
 AWS_ACCESS_KEY=my_aws_access_key
AWS_SECRET_KEY=my_super_secret_key
```

That’s all that’s needed to host your dependencies on Amazon S3, allowing you an affordable, access controlled option for internal maven hosting without the management overhead.

***Note***: ***Not a solution for open source libraries***

BinTray (jcenter) and Maven Central are the place to distribute open source code. This allows users of your libraries easy access without the need to add custom repositories throughout their projects. This is only the solution when you need an authenticated repository, or if you need to distribute your library without the source code (ala Fabric).

For More information on this check these links :

[An S3 repository can be configured to authenticate using AWS's EC2 instance metadata.](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/finding-and-using-credentials.md#story-an-s3-repository-can-be-configured-to-authenticate-using-awss-ec2-instance-metadata/)

[S3 Repositories can be configured with credentials providers](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/finding-and-using-credentials.md#story-s3-repositories-can-be-configured-with-credentials-providers)

[Setting Up & Publishing Private Amazon S3 Maven Repository Android Library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library#setting-up-a-private-amazon-s3-maven-repository)

Happy Coding !!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your library is open-source you can use https://jitpack.io for free

Comment: thank you for reply.my library is not open source larsgrefer yar.